# Algebraic topology on function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I study algebraic topology using hatchers book. So far, most of the encountered examples are (low dimensional) manifolds. Therefore I was wondering, if the introduced concepts are of any use for investigating continuous maps between infinite dimensional spaces (other than $\mathbb R P^\infty$, etc), like the standard $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ spaces?

I guess that the theory is not suitable when dealing wiht spaces with infinite (diferent) path components. But I have no clue, how many path components these spaces have.

Are there any books about this subject I could study?

Comment: My gut says that tools developed for abstracting away useful information from low dimensional settings would need some significant tweaking in order to lift them into an infinite dimensional setting. I am far from an expert in the subject, but I'm aware of no really nontrivial invariants that are preserved when moving from a finite-dimensional version of a structure to an infinite dimensional version, particularly if the dimension is uncountable or larger.

Comment: In the countable case, one can sometimes induct over the dimension, for examle if the space is an cw-complex.

Comment: Aren't $L^p$ spaces vector spaces?  They would be contractible, and therefore "uninteresting" to algebraic topology.  On the other hand, an instance of understanding function spaces in algebraic topology is [Kuiper's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_theorem).

Comment: @JHF the OP likely is interested in manifolds or other constructions modelled on these infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: What about subsets though? Finite dimensional vectorspaces, i.e $\mathbb R^n$ have plenty of interesting subsets like spheres, tori...
I already know, that infinitedimensional spheres are contractible independent of the base space.

Comment: Although Hatcher is mostly motivated by the finite, or at least finite-dimensional, case, most of the material there applies without modification to the case of an arbitrary CW-complex. It also covers a few examples, relegated to exercises, of pathological spaces that aren't in the CW-category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in Hilbert cube manifolds (search on that term in Google), which were introduced by Chapman around 1970 and were used to solve problems in the topology of finite dimensional manifolds and CW complexes.

Comment: That looks interesting, thx